# background process in a running application in Java

Tags: java

I am developing a new application and I have to log the method name in the table when a specific method is called, but I have to do this as background process and this process should not affect the application. Please advise how to do this

Comment: https://www.google.de/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=vMieU-nNNKqH8QfvnoG4CA#q=java+thread

Comment: Use log4j..and log method name inside each method

Comment: We need more information than this.. This is more like a logging system. Why not use frameworks like Log4J?. Every Java program runs in its own instance of JVM, so I don't know how creating a seperate process(instead of a thread) will help. Next if you create a seperate logging thread, then the performance of your program will be affected.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are confused with terminology.

Background process is a process that is running without interaction with user. For example you can say that OS services are background processes.

If you want something like this in java program you need background thread. However it seems that it is not what you need now because you want to log each method call, i.e. definitely not background.

So, you can add log int the beginning of each method that will work but sounds a bad idea. Alternatively you can use AOP (e.g. AspectJ) to perform this task. Take a look on any beginning tutorial of AspectJ: this is a classical task to perform with it. TIP: learn a little bit about AspectJ, then move to annotation based implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I want to log only one method name with the timestamp in the table. I have implemented it with AOP. Is there a option to run this AOP in the background without using Threads

Comment: Again, what do you mean when you say "background"? You want to log the method calls, don't you? In this case it is not "running in background". If you however want to (for example) count method calls but create report periodically, the report thread will run in background.